# logout not working in flutter firebase authentication app with multiple screens

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication

i have setup a flutter app with firebase auth, the whole authentication process is good(sign in, sign up and sign out), however when i created multiple screens and navigated using Navigator.pushReplacement, the app only signs out if i attempt without navigating to any other screens, when i attempt after navigating the signout stops working.

i have tried pushReplacemnt and pop as well, it either navigates to login screen without signing out or signs out without going to login screen. i want to be able to sign out successfully then redirected to login screen and be able to login again.

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:vijayadwaja/pages/loginpage.dart';

import 'profile.dart';
import 'bulkorders.dart';
import 'family.dart';
import 'subscription.dart';
import 'orders.dart';
import 'settings.dart';

class MyDrawer extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyDrawer({
    super.key,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Drawer(
      backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(207, 22, 22, 1),
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.white,
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Container(
              decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                color: Color.fromRGBO(207, 22, 22, 1),
                // borderRadius:
                //     BorderRadius.only(bottomRight: Radius.circular(30)),
              ),
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 60.0, bottom: 25.0),
                child: ListTile(
                  leading: CircleAvatar(
                    backgroundColor: Colors.grey[300],
                    child: const Icon(
                      Icons.person_2_rounded,
                      color: Color.fromRGBO(207, 22, 22, 1),
                    ),
                  ),
                  title: const Text(
                    'John Doe',
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w600, color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                  subtitle: const Text(
                    '+91 12345 67890',
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white70),
                  ),
                  onTap: () {
                    Navigator.pushReplacement(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) {
                          return UserProfile();
                        },
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Column(
              children: [
                const Divider(
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
                ListTile(
                  leading: const Icon(Icons.subscriptions_rounded),
                  title: const Text('Subscription'),
                  onTap: () {
                    Navigator.pushReplacement(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) {
                          return const Subscription();
                        },
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                ),
                ListTile(
                  leading: const Icon(Icons.inventory_2_rounded),
                  title: const Text('My Orders'),
                  onTap: () {
                    Navigator.pushReplacement(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) {
                          return const MyOrders();
                        },
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                ),
                ListTile(
                  leading: const Icon(Icons.local_shipping),
                  title: const Text('Bulk Orders'),
                  onTap: () {
                    Navigator.pushReplacement(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) {
                          return const BulkOrders();
                        },
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                ),
                ListTile(
                  leading: const Icon(Icons.family_restroom),
                  title: const Text('My Family'),
                  onTap: () {
                    Navigator.pushReplacement(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) {
                          return const MyFamily();
                        },
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                ),
                const Divider(color: Colors.black38),
                ListTile(
                  leading: const Icon(Icons.notifications),
                  title: const Text('Notifications'),
                  onTap: () {
                    Navigator.pushReplacement(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) {
                          return const Settings();
                        },
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                ),
                ListTile(
                  leading: const Icon(Icons.settings),
                  title: const Text('Settings'),
                  onTap: () {
                    Navigator.pushReplacement(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) {
                          return const Settings();
                        },
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                ),
                const Divider(color: Colors.black38),
                ListTile(
                  leading: const Icon(Icons.logout),
                  title: const Text('Log Out'),
                  onTap: () async {
                    try {
                      await FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
                      Navigator.pop;
                      // Navigator.pushReplacement(
                      //   context,
                      //   MaterialPageRoute(
                      //       builder: (context) =>
                      //           const LoginPage()),
                      // );
                    } catch (e) {
                      print('Error signing out: $e');
                    }
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.whenComplete` or `.then` like this:

```
ListTile(
 leading: const Icon(Icons.logout),
 title: const Text('Log Out'),
 onTap: () async {
    try {
      await FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut().whenComplete(
      () => Navigator.pop(context),
      );
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error signing out: $e');
    }
   },
),
```

Comment: it does sign out, but doesnt go to loginpage, i added pushReplacemnt navigator to login page, but login doesnt work

Comment: @SonuNadig Can you provide the debug console output when you attempt to log in?

Comment: Do you actually need popUntil because there's more than one screen between you and login now? https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Navigator/popUntil.html

Comment: i figured out the issue, after sign out i pointed it to Streambuilder widget which checks the authentication state instead of directly navigating to login page (my stream builder widget is separate from loginpage widget)

Answer (score 0):

the issue was that after triggering signout, it was navigating directly to login page instead of checking the authentication state via stream builder.
so navigating to a widget which returns streambuilder and checks the authentication state after signout was the fix.

```
class WidgetTree extends StatefulWidget {
  const WidgetTree({super.key});

  @override
  State<WidgetTree> createState() => _WidgetTreeState();
}

class _WidgetTreeState extends State<WidgetTree> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder(
        stream: Auth().authStateChanges,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return const Subscription();
          } else {
            return const LoginPage();
          }
        });
  }
}
```